# WPF Combobox not updating in twoways

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, prism

I am binding a combobox with a varaible on my PLC so when i change the combobox the changed value transmitted to my PLC but when i change on my PLC the combobox wont change even if the field is changed

I put a brakepoint on the field(the one i bind to SelectedItem) to check if it changes and it did but didn't affect the combobox

Here is my ViewModel

```
    List<string> _temperatureList = new List<string> { "80 °C", "100 °C", "120 °C" };

    public List<string> TemperatureList
    {
        get { return _temperatureList; }
    }

    public  string Temperature
    {

        get
        { 
            return (TemperatureGS != 0) ?  string.Format("{0} °C", TemperatureGS) : "80 °C";
        }
        set
        {
            TemperatureGS = Convert.ToSByte(value.Replace(" °C", ""));
            OnPropertyChanged();
            WriteTemperature(TemperatureGS);
        }
    }

    private short _temperature ;

    public short TemperatureGS
    {
        get { return _temperature; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _temperature, value); }
    }



 public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
        {

            TemperatureGS = PLCread(0);
            OnPropertyChanged(Temperature);

        }
```

My Xaml code

```
 <ComboBox  SelectedItem="{Binding Temperature, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"  
ItemsSource="{Binding TemperatureList }"  />
```

Comment: How's your OnPropertyChanged implemented?

Comment: Shouldn’t the Temperature in OnPropertyChanged be in double quotes?

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota I dont know but it seems working like that

Comment: Can you show the code for OnPropertyChanged()?